# showing a element on mouseover and hiding it on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have this small script that shows a caption for a img when it is moused over.

```
    $("#v1").mouseover(function() 
    {
        $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

How can I expand on this so that the caption `#vc1` fades back out when the icon `#v1` is not moused over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $("#v1")
      .mouseover(function() {
        $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow"); 
      })
      .mouseout(function() {
        $("#vc1").fadeOut("slow");
      });
```

Might consider using hover, which is essentially `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
    $("#v1")
      .hover(
          function() {
              $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow"); 
          },
          function() {
              $("#vc1").fadeOut("slow");
      });
```

The difference is that `mouseover` and `mouseout` will fire when you move into a child element of the element to which the event handler is attached, whereas `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` a.k.a. `hover` won't. This may not be a problem if the element to which you're attaching doesn't have children.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work:

```
$("#v1").hover(function() 
{
    $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow");
}, function( )
{
    $("#vc1").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

And htt://api.jquery.com is nice resource which can help a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseout` together with `mouseover` (or use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead, depending on what behaviour you want when the mouse is in a child of `#v1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hover function.

```
  $("#v1").hover(function(){
    $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow");

   }, function(){
     $("#vc1").fadeOut("slow");

    });
```